# database design for online system using adjacency list model

Tags: asp.net, mysql, database-design, hierarchical-data, adjacency-list-model

i am trying to create a online shopping application using asp.net c# and mysql,
i have many categories which has two level subcategories and and some categories do not have subcategories somewhat like:

```
1.clothing   
1.1-mens                    
     1.1.1-shirts                          
     1.1.2-trousers
     1.1.3-jeans  
1.2-womens      
     1.2.1-casual  
     1.2.2-jeans  
2.Books  
 -tecnhology  
 -medical  
 -history   

3.mobiles
  3.1-nokia  
  3.2-samsung   
  3.3-Apple   
  3.4-accesories   
    3.4.1-headset   
    3.4.2-cases and chargers    

4.movies         
  4.1-action    
  4.2-horror   
  4.3-romance
```

*My First question is- *should i create separate tables for each category using adjacency list model because i have started to learn about this model and i have seen examples that only one root node is used in adjacency list model.
*My Second question is- *whether i can add multiple root nodes in adjacency list model and can add add products and traverse to the specific categories using a parent. 
thanks.. help appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple root nodes, even in the same table.  A root node is any node which has no parent.  Typically, you just set parent_id=null to make the node a root of its tree.

I don't think there's any need to store each category in a separate table.

You may also be interested in my presentation, [Models for Hierarchical Data with SQL and PHP](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data) (the PHP part is a very small part of the material).

Comment: After viewing your nice presentation sir, could i still use adjacency list or should i opt for closure table instead..i am not sure that i am going to add any new nodes. is it ok to use adjacency list in this model what can be the drawbacks.. what do you recommend

Comment: Queries are simpler with Adjacency List, if you can rely on the depth of the tree being limited.